# Non-linear optimization with unit vector constraint

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix, E, and I'm trying to solve this optimization problem:

```
|| E * t || = minimum
```

where t is the solution I'm looking for and it MUST be a unit vector (represented as a 3x1 matrix). || x || denotes the euclidean distance of x.

Is there a library that can help me solve this problem? I've found a couple of solve functions in various libraries, but I can't seem to find one that'll let me put on the additional constraint that t must be a unit vector. Can I solve this programmatically without a library then?

Comment: With unit vector, do you mean a vector of unit length (`||t||==1` or one of the set `(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)`?

Comment: I mean the former, ||t|| == 1. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an eigenvector-type problem to me -- your `minimum` should be the smallest absolute value among the eigenvalues of `E`.

Do a [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD) of the matrix E (this operation should be available as part of any good linear algebra library).  This will give you a factorization of E as:

```
E =  U diag V*
```

where `diag` is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative diagonal values, and `U` and `V` are orthonormal.

Find the smallest diagonal element of `diag`; the corresponding row of `V*` (or column of `V`) is your solution for `t`.

This value for `t` will be a unit vector because `V` is orthonormal, and the resulting vector `E t` will be smallest because `U` and `V` preserve vector length.